# Is it possible to "regroup" data by array values without flattening/exploding? (spark)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

Let's say you have the following data:

```
id1, [f1, f2], [x_id1, x_id2]
id2, [f1, f4], [x_id3, x_id2]
id3, [f3, f2], [x_id1, x_id3]
```

and you'd like to get this:

```
x_id1, [id1, id3], [[f1, f2],[f3, f2]] 
x_id2, [id1, id2], [[f1, f2],[f1, f4]]
x_id3, [id2, id3], [[f1, f4],[f3, f2]]
```

I'm wondering if here's a tricky way to do tis transformation without flattening/exploding the data. If we're not thinking in distributed system we can easily iterate on the x_id array and fill a hashmap (or whatever storage), but with RDDs I had to flatten out the data:

```
id1, [f1, f2], x_id1
id1, [f1, f2], x_id2
id2, [f1, f4], x_id3
id2, [f1, f4], x_id2
id3, [f3, f2], x_id1
id3, [f3, f2], x_id3
```

And than easily run out of memory. We're talking about few 100M ids, feature size is 1k-10k and 100-1k x_id.
Is there any tricky way to do it without flattening?

Comment: is the [x_id1, x_id2] always an array of 2? If so you can convert this to a key value pair with x_id1 as the key and then groupby it.

Comment: the x_id space is about 100-1000 (as I mentioned) varies id by id, so the pair does not help

Comment: If the issue is performance only, you can try using dataframes instead of RDD (you would still need to explode the data but hopefully it will be good enough)

Comment: My issue is memory, it just grows huge. To give a hint about scale we're talking about: 6000 executor 18GB each and the data does not fit after flatten.

Comment: in general dataframes take an order of magnitude less memory than RDD due to project tungsten. Also catalyst optimization may be able to reduce the data needed at any one time by adding behind the scenes optimizations and whole stage code gen could also do so because the data might not materialize.

Comment: I'll definitely try it with dataframe, thanks